# how can I find the frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, frequency

I have this data frame. How can I find the 3 most repeated number in column b?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,2,4,2,3], "b": [np.nan, np.nan, '2,3', 3, '3,5,1',2]})
```

I guess the answer should be 3,2,5 or 3,2,1

Comment: what if np.nan is the most frequent, do you want that to be included?

Comment: Oh sorry I should drop them first

Comment: ===== Kenneth ? =====

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` the column `b` around the delimiter `,`, then use `explode` to transform each element in list like to rows, finally use `value_counts` + `head` to get the top 3 repeated elements:

```
df['b'].dropna().astype(str).str.split(',')\
       .explode().value_counts().head(3).index.tolist()
```

`explode` is available in pandas version >= `0.25`, for pandas version < `0.25` use:

```
pd.value_counts(np.hstack(df['b'].dropna().astype(str).str.split(','))).head(3).index.tolist()
```

---

```
['3', '2', '5']
```

Comment: I am getting this error,  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: I think you are using the old pandas version, is it possible to upgrade pandas?

Comment: yes, you are right. I was using a cloud system so ... it worked on my personal computer

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of pandas and python `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

a = list(dict(Counter(df.b.dropna().astype(str).str.split(',').sum()).most_common(3))
                                   .keys())

In [132]: a
Out[132]: ['3', '2', '5']
```